# Navbar no actualiza luego del sign-in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

tengo el siguiente problema con una aplicacion en la que estoy, estoy en el componente y luego que el usuario ingresa sus credenciales y obtiene la respuesta del servidor (token) el navbar no actualiza *a menos que yo lo refresque manualmente*, luego del sign in redirige a home ('/').

Estuve intentando pasar los states por props al componente en la funcion sig in, pero sin exito.

```
        // setting localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('token', get_token);
        this.setState({
            isLogged: true
        });

        this.props.history.push('/');
        "aqui por pathname: '/', state.."
```

Actualmente mi codigo es el siguiente:

**Componente sign in:**

```
    // React
    import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

    // React apollo
    import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
    import * as compose from 'lodash.flowright';

    // React router
    import { withRouter, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

    // import mutations
    import mutations from './mutations';

    // React bootstrap
    import { Container, Row, Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

    // Import Style
    import './style.css';

    // Component
    import NavbarLayout from '../Navbar';



    class LoginForm extends React.Component {

        state = {
            login_credentials: {},
            isLogged: false
        }

        get_data = async(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const { name, value } = e.target;
            const data = { [name]: value };
            const newData = { ...this.state.login_credentials, ...data };
            this.setState({
                login_credentials: newData
            });

        }

        submit = async(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const { signinUser } = this.props;
            const { login_credentials, isLogged } = this.state;

            try {
                let variables = login_credentials;
                const response = await signinUser({variables});
                const get_token = response.data.signinUser.token;

                // setting localStorage
                localStorage.setItem('token', get_token);
                this.setState({
                    isLogged: true
                });

                this.props.history.push('/');


            } catch(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }


        }


        render() {

            return(
                <Fragment>
                <Container>
                    <Form className="form-container">
                        <h2 className="text-center pb-4">Ingreso</h2>
                        <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
                            <Form.Control name='email' onChange={e => this.get_data(e)} type="email" placeholder="Email" />
                        </Form.Group>

                        <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
                            <Form.Control name='password' onChange={e => this.get_data(e)} type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" />
                        </Form.Group>
                        <div className="text-center">
                            <Button className="button-login" variant="primary" onClick={e => this.submit(e)} type="submit">
                                Ingresa
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                    </Form>
                </Container>
                </Fragment>
            );
        }
    }

    export default compose(
        withRouter,
        graphql(mutations.signinUser, { name: 'signinUser' }),
    )(LoginForm);
```

**componente navbar:**

```
    // React
    import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

    // React router
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

    // React apollo
    import * as compose from 'lodash.flowright';

    // React Components
    import { Home } from '../../views/Home'; 
    import { LoginPage } from '../../views/Login';

    // React bootstrap
    import { Navbar, Form, Nav, NavDropdown, Button, FormControl } from 'react-bootstrap';
    import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';

    // Mutations
    import mutations from './mutations';


    class NavbarLayout extends React.Component {


        componentDidMount() {

        }


        signOut = async(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const { signoutUser } = this.props;
            try {
                await signoutUser();
                localStorage.removeItem('token');
            } catch(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }


        render() {


            const user_token = localStorage.getItem('token') || '';

            return(
                <Fragment>
                    <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
                        <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Sample App</Navbar.Brand>
                        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                            <Nav className="ml-auto">
                            <Nav.Link><Link to="/">Home</Link></Nav.Link>
                            {user_token ? (
                                <Fragment>
                                    <Nav.Link onClick={e => this.signOut(e)}>Salir</Nav.Link>
                                    <Nav.Link>Publicar</Nav.Link>
                                </Fragment>
                            ):(
                            <Nav.Link><Link to="/sign-in">Entrar</Link></Nav.Link>
                            )}
                            </Nav>

                        </Navbar.Collapse>

                    </Navbar>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/sign-in" component={LoginPage} />
                    </Switch>

                </Fragment>
            );
        }
    }

    export default compose(
        withRouter,
        graphql(mutations.signoutUser, { name: 'signoutUser' })
    )(NavbarLayout)
```

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta a mi problema fue usar context api de React para poder tener centralizados los states y ademas poder a traves de los consumidores hacer condicionales que me permitan hacer el update del navbar

**Navbar:**

```
        // React
    import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

    // React router
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

    // React apollo
    import * as compose from 'lodash.flowright';

    // React Components
    import LoginPage from '../../views/Login';
    import Header from '../../views/Home/Header';
    import Home from '../../views/Home/index';

    // React bootstrap
    import { Navbar, Form, Nav, NavDropdown, Button, FormControl } from 'react-bootstrap';
    import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';

    // Mutations
    import mutations from './mutations';

    // Context 
    import { Context } from '../../context/context';

    class NavbarLayout extends React.Component {


        render() {

            return(
                <Context.Consumer>
                {c => {

                    return(
                        <Fragment>
                        <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
                        <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Sample App</Navbar.Brand>
                        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                            <Nav className="ml-auto">
                            <Nav.Link><Link to="/home">Home</Link></Nav.Link>
                            {localStorage.getItem('isLogged') ? 
                            (
                                <Fragment>
                                    <Nav.Link onClick={e => c.signOut(e)}>Salir</Nav.Link>
                                    <Nav.Link>Publicar</Nav.Link>
                                </Fragment>

                            ) : 
                            (
                                <Nav.Link><Link to="/sign-in">Entrar</Link></Nav.Link>
                            )}
                            </Nav>
                        </Navbar.Collapse>

                    </Navbar>

                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/sign-in" component={LoginPage} />
                </Switch>
                </Fragment>
                    );
                }}
                </Context.Consumer>
            );
        }
    }

    export default compose(
        withRouter,
        graphql(mutations.signoutUser, { name: 'signoutUser' })
    )(NavbarLayout)
```

**context:**

```
        // React
    import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

    // React apollo
    import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
    import * as compose from 'lodash.flowright';

    // React router
    import { withRouter, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

    // Mutation
    import mutations from './mutations';

    // Context
    export const Context = React.createContext();

    class AppProvider extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
                this.state = {
                    // Login & logout states
                    login_credentials: {},
                    isLogged: false,
                    get_data: this.get_data,
                    submit: this.submit,
                    signOut: this.signOut
                }
            }

            // Actions

            // Login & Logout

            get_data = async(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                const { name, value } = e.target;
                const data = { [name]: value };
                const newData = { ...this.state.login_credentials, ...data };
                this.setState({
                    login_credentials: newData
                });

            }

            submit = async(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                const { signinUser } = this.props;
                const { login_credentials } = this.state;

                try {
                    let variables = login_credentials;
                    const response = await signinUser({variables});
                    const get_token = response.data.signinUser.token;

                    // setting localStorage
                    localStorage.setItem('token', get_token);

                    this.setState({
                        isLogged: true
                    }); 

                    localStorage.setItem('isLogged', this.state.isLogged);

                    this.props.history.push('/home');


                } catch(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }

            }


            signOut = async(e) => {

                e.preventDefault();
                const { signoutUser } = this.props;
                try {   
                    await signoutUser();
                    localStorage.removeItem('token');
                    localStorage.removeItem('isLogged');
                    this.setState({
                        isLogged: false
                    });

                } catch(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }
        // END LOGIN & LOGOUT ACTIONS

        render() {
            return(
                <Context.Provider value={this.state}>
                    {this.props.children}
                </Context.Provider>
            );
        }
    }

    export default compose(
        withRouter,
        graphql(mutations.signinUser, { name: 'signinUser' }),
        graphql(mutations.signoutUser, { name: 'signoutUser' })
    )(AppProvider)
```